# Numpy installing via PyPI vs distro package manager

Tags: python, ubuntu, numpy, scipy

This is probably a trivial question and maybe even a duplicate.

What is the difference between numpy/scipy as installed from PyPI and as opposed to the one installed from a distribution's repository, say Ubuntu using apt-get? I think I have a vague idea- numpy as installed from PyPI requires a lot of other tools like gcc, gfortran before it can build. I am guessing a distro's version of numpy package comes with all these tools? Not sure if this is the right picture.

If so, using PyPI depending on which python I am pointing to I can install numpy and scipy for a particular version of python. Using apt-get, can you install numpy and scipy for a specific version of python? Does the package manager apt-get use the version of python I am pointing to?

Answer (score 3):

The main difference is that, in pip you have a always a fresh version, in 
ubuntu repository you always have a little outdated python package.

And yes you can install for example python-numpy or python3-numpy and that will download all dependency -> http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/python-numpy. 
the same is with PyPI, you can use pip/pip3 to install package that you want, but that can be more 'tricky', because sometimes you must find a dependency manually. Like with ipython-notebook, when you install from apt-get, everything will be downloaded and you don't care about dependency, but when you want a fresh version and you download this from pip, you must also install tornado,jsonscheme, pyzqt manually with using pip.

And with using pip/apt-get you can install numpy/scikit for different python version. (in ubuntu default version of python is 2.7 so when you install sth for python3 you must add 3 ;) )
apt-get install python-numpy /pip install numpy
or
apt-get install python3-numpy/ pip3 install numpy
and the same with scikit :)

Comment: ... except when pypi has an older/abandoned version and the distros have a newer upstream one.  That happens too.

Answer (score 3):

The majority of Linux distributions have a package manager that installs pre-compiled binary packages. In the case of numpy/scipy they would thus install Python source code with the precompiled C/Fortran extensions. No C/Fortran compilers are necessary for the install.

PyPI on the other hand, is a package manager for Python that is very roughly a wrapper around the `python setup.py install` command. It will in particular compile the necessary C/Fortran extensions from sources. It thus requires the `gcc`, `gfortran` compilers to be present on the system. This takes longer (~15 min for numpy) but has the advantage that it could be potentially optimized with compilation flags to the current CPU architecture and therefore marginally faster (that shouldn't matter much in practice though).

Comment: Great. That makes sense. Can you shed some light on the latter part of my question where using pip, depending on which version of python I am pointing to(python2 or python3) numpy gets installed for that particular version. Using apt-get can you install numpy for a specific version of python?